# Different meanings of 加減

Tags: meaning, words

I know 加減 has [a number of meaning](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%8A%A0%E6%B8%9B), and I'm having trouble understanding it in several sentences; last one I heard is from *RDG* episode 7 (all said by the same character, I keep the separation in the subtitles so I won't add punctuation):

> 私が相楽くんを巻き込んだんだ
>
> 思わずそう言ったらそれが真相だったことに気がついた
>
> 期待していると思いたくなくて‌
>
> 真響さんには相楽くんを貶し加減に言っていたことも‌

The word per se means a degree of something, adjusting something by adding or removing, doing something in moderation; for example, いい加減にしろ is usually translated as "Stop it", I think from a more literal meaning of "Do it in a good degree" (i.e., not too much, so now you are exaggerating and have to stop).

But how should I read it in the sentence above? That the character is speaking ill of the other one to a certain degree and/or in an acceptable manners sounds odd. Maybe like いい加減にしろ means that they are past the acceptable limit? If so, I don't really understand the sentence construction, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is still the *degree*, but [大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%8A%A0%E6%B8%9B/#jn-39754) has the following definition:

> ［接尾］動詞の連用形や状態を表す名詞に付く。
>
> ２ そのような傾向、そのような気味である、の意を表す。「うつむき―」

The usage means: with such a tendency/inclination, which I think derives from *with a degree of something*.

Practically, it works as a weakening ("just a tendency, not fully so"), so 貶{けな}し加減に言っていた means *kind of/slightly spoke ill of*.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, and I'm not really sure of the context, but I would interpret 「真響さんには相楽くんを貶し**加減**に言っていた」as basically saying:

"was saying things to Mayura that **amounted to** disrespecting Sagara."

That is, what was being said *reached the level* of being disrespectful (even if possibly that wasn't the intent).